# How to access Ubuntu running Openfire from the Internet (Public IP)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nat, port-forwarding

I have Openfire installed in my Ubuntu server using port 7070. Now using [ipchicken](http://www.ipchicken.com/) I found my public IP (example: 111.11.000.0/7070).  When I try connecting from another PC through connected to the Internet the Ubuntu server is not accessible.

How to config the firewall in Ubuntu so that I can access it using the public IP? 
Please guide me with a step by step example since I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: The phrasing of your question does not make this very important point clear: is the computer you're connecting _from_ on the same LAN or not?
If it is, it usually depends on the router to route traffic to your own public IP back to the appropriate local, internal IP address.

Comment: Did you set port forwarding up properly on your router?